# How to cast column with nested array in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have this schema in pyspark:

```
root
 |-- SortedLenders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- LenderID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- MaxProfit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FilteredOutDecisions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ApprovedAmount: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Reasons: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

How do I cast **FilteredOutDecisions.Reasons** column to double? Thank you, in advance!

Comment: Cast to what? What's your expected outcome?

Comment: let's say double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('newFilteredOutDecisions', f.expr('transform(FilteredOutDecisions, element -> struct(element.ApprovedAmount as ApprovedAmount, transform(element.Reasons, value -> cast (value as double)) as Reasons))'))
)
```